# 14.04 System hangs and IO errors

Tags: 14.04, ssd, crash, io

To my surprise, after todays fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install (fully updated as of today) I'm getting various problems like random hangs and `I/O` errors when copying/moving files (moving backup from HDD to SSD - checked both drives and there aren't any bad sectors). I heard 14.04 enabled `TRIM` by default and I'm not sure if it's causing the problem or not.

- Im pretty sure my system hangs due to I/O problems, any idea?
- Using Ubuntu since 11.04 and never had problem like that before.

**Partitions**:

```
SSD:

sda1 - EXT4 - /              18GB 
sda2 - EXT4 - /home         110GB

HDD:

sdb1 - EXT4 - /media/Misc   600GB 
sdb2 - EXT4 - /media/Games  400GB
```

**Specs**:

- Intel i7-3770k
- 8GB Ram
- nVidia GTX770 4GB (331 driver blob installed from drivers menu)
- ADATA 128GB SSD | 1TB Segate HDD.

Comment: I'm running 14.04 on a Samsung 840 EVO 500 GB ssd. I've been seeing the system freeze up somewhat frequently (few times today) and then sometimes crash. I'm dual booting with Windows 7 which has had no problems at all. It definitely seems to be I/O error related, but the drive is brand new and seems fine from all diagnostics.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with the 500 GB 840EVO with a fresh install of 14.04. Also dual booting win7 but don't see how that would matter unless it is due to wacky partitioning or something. The SSD is running fine in windows so hardware seems generally okay.

Answer (score -1):

When I installed the latest OS upgrade I had the same issue, I just ran though the full set of sudo apt-get commands then I did a software update check and after all that i ran sudo apt-get autoremove and and autoclean and it fixed the issue

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please include the **"full set"** of `sudo apt-get` commands and **all** the other steps you did to resolve the issue in your answer. Answers are only useful if others can follow your trail.